# What has changed with the Uber API? Has the server been shut down? Any plan to reopen soon?

Tags: uber-api

Our OAuth module worked perfectly until last week. We know Uber changed the terms of its API and we've been unable to access the server since then.

We've tried creating a different Dev account, contacting the Uber dev team,  tweeting them, reached out to people internally who pointed us to stack overflow, we've filled the automated form requesting for our access to be maintained, ...

Our swift code where we fetch the Uber API data

```
let datafetcher = UberDataFetch(oauth2: self.oauth2)
self.uber.products = try! datafetcher.getProductData(data:     self.uber)
```

Our error message

```
[Debug] OAuth2: Starting authorization
[Debug] OAuth2: Have an apparently unexpired access token
[Debug] OAuth2: Storing tokens to keychain
[Debug] OAuth2: Initialization finished
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an     Optional value
```

Answer (score 0):

Uber is currently changing their API access, it killed many applications, mine included, somehow users that were logged in can still use it like normal, but log in has become impossible for whatever reason, so new users can't use my app, or old users that logged out. I also tried contacting in every channel possible like you, no response anywhere too.

Comment: Thx Danilo! Looks like we’re not the only ones indeed. Still no news from Uber on my end. Any chance on yours?

Comment: Nope, complete radio silence on all fronts